# ¿Se pueden actualizar apps creadas en React Native a Kotlin o Swift sin problemas desde las tiendas?

Tags: android, ios, swift, react-native, kotlin

Tengo una empresa que tiene una aplicación en la tienda de Google y otra en la tienda de Apple, ambas están creadas en React Native, pero ya no quieren seguir usándolo y quieren cambiar a los idiomas nativos de las plataformas, Kotlin y Swift respectivamente. Sin embargo, tengo la duda si podré actualizar ambas versiones sin problemas a los idiomas nativos en cada una de las tiendas, ya que nunca me ha tocado hacer algo así. O sea, ¿se realizarán las actualizaciones de las apps de una tecnología a otra sin problemas?

Comment: Si se puede, debes ver qué código puedes reutilizar de React Native y lo demás codificar en el lenguaje nativo.

Comment: @Bicho, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero la idea es dejar react native y pasarlo todo a nativo, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para actualizar tus aplicaciones inicialmente creadas con React native ahora nativamente, no debes tener ningún problema

**Android**

**Solo es importante firmar el .APK con la misma Keystore con la que fue firmada tu versión anterior creada en React Native.**

Puede comparar el proceso para subir y firmar a Google Play Store una app React Native:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

y una aplicación Nativa:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

**iOS**

En cuanto actualizar tu aplicación nativa en la App Store, es el mismo procedimiento, **debes usar los mismos certificados generados de tu cuenta Apple developer** y subir tu archivo .ipa

Comment: Muchas gracias por compartir tus conocimientos. Me quedó totalmente claro, saludos.